# Create logs or table with logs panel in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I use [iDRAC exporter](https://github.com/mrlhansen/idrac_exporter) to get some metrics from HW servers. Metrics are contain events:

```
idrac_sel_entry{component="Physical Chassis Security",id="83",message="OEM software event.",severity="OK"} 1.584046468e+09
idrac_sel_entry{component="Physical Chassis Security",id="910",message="The chassis is open while the power is off.",severity="Critical"} 1.671263315e+09
idrac_sel_entry{component="Physical Chassis Security",id="915",message="The chassis is closed while the power is off.",severity="OK"} 1.671224792e+09
idrac_sel_entry{component="Power Supply / Converter",id="911",message="The Power Supply Unit (PSU) 2 is not receiving input power because of issues in PSU or cable connections.",severity="Critical"} 1.671263323e+09
idrac_sel_entry{component="Power Supply / Converter",id="914",message="The input power for power supply 2 has been restored.",severity="OK"} 1.671224014e+09
idrac_sel_entry{component="Power Supply / Converter",id="928",message="The Power Supply Unit (PSU) 1 is not receiving input power because of issues in PSU or cable connections.",severity="Critical"} 1.67864103e+09
```

I want to show all critical logs in Grafana panel, I use metric **idrac_sel_entry** with label filter **host** and **severity="Critical"**,
[image]
and when I choose [Logs visualisation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/logs/) i get message **Data is missing a string field** without data:
[image]
I tried switch to **table view**, but string messages really not exists:
[image]

How I can show that logs, for example like table with datetime and message fields?

Comment: Change type of the query to table in query options (under the query editor). And use table panel: this is not real logs, and I don't think it's possible to convince Grafana otherwise.

Comment: Additionally, prometheus is not really designed for storing logs in this way, and you might encounter some issues with this approach. Consider using a designated log scraping and storing solution, like Loki, for this kind of things.